# docker dns for set of running containers

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, containers

I have a docker image which provides a given service on $PORT.

When running multiple instances of this container with docker-compose, I can access all their ip's from inside the network with dig (other dns tools are available).

How can I acheive this same result from the docker command line client and the python library?

Answer (score 3):

One way to acheive this is to [connect the docker containers to a network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/) with an alias, you can connect multiple containers to the same network with the same alias, these can then be seen in the response to a dns lookup.

```
$ docker create network --name test-nwk
$ docker run --name test-service-1 busybox
$ docker run --name test-service-w busybox
$ docker network connect test-nwk test-service-1 --alias test-service
$ docker network connect test-nwk test-service-2 --alias test-service
```

now when you connect another container to that network you can see them both visible form the domain `test-service`

```
$ docker run -it --name test busybox sh
/ # nslookup test-service
Server:    127.0.0.11
Address 1: 127.0.0.11

Name:      test-service
Address 1: 172.18.0.3 test-service-2.test-nwk
Address 2: 172.18.0.2 test-service-1.test-nwk
```

Comment: shouldn't that be docker network create test-nwk?

Comment: Also, when I do  nslookup test-service I get Can't find test-service.mydomain.de: No answer